# incomplete scraped HTML page by OkHttp3, javascript needed?

Tags: java, okhttp

I am scraping some JSON data from a website which works pretty well. I can login and download the necessary data. However, in one case I have to download a HTML page to extract the info from the HTML.

I've modified the request headers such that they match the ones that were visibile using Chrome developer options (F12).

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                    .header("Host", "www.host.com")
                    .header("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                    .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
                    .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
                    .header("User-Agent",this.user_agent_user_for_this_session)
                    .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,af;q=0.5")
                    .get().build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String html = IOUtils.toString(new GZIPInputStream(response.body().byteStream()));
```

I receive a HTML file but it is much smaller as compared to the HTML file that is saved manually from Chrome (save source as). I noticed all kinds of ng (angular) references in the HTML file which made me wonder if I only received the first part of a certain javascript process that was not finished?

In addition, the HTML that is downloaded looks identical to the HTML file that is downloaded in the first network view of Chrome (i copy pasted the content and the file sizes are the same).

So should I allow for some additional analyses on the request?

Answer (score 1):

If it is angular page then you are out of luck - whole page is generated on runtime so actual `index.html` is kind of small.

As workaround I have used Selenium to actually open page in headless browser and fetch content after angular application is initialized (aka DOM is built).

Comment: But wouldn't that require that I would have to re-login with the Selenium instance in order to have the right login access? Now everything is initialized using a form login with okhttp

Comment: Usually I was hijacking the session for that ;)

Comment: That sounds cool :-). Any tutorial links how to to do that? So you're basically using the session of okhttp with selenium?

Comment: Never used one, did it myself.  If you would be stubborn enough, you would be able to serve webpage to the browser via okhttp client so the session would be in plase already ;) But I think that in your case session hijack is simpler way to do what you want to do insteed of creating web proxy.

Comment: I am currently scraping using cloud based serverless Java instances. So basically headless Java. Would that pose a problem for the Selenium approach? If I am reading it correctly, it somehow still uses some kind of Chrome or other Browser component?

Comment: yep as it opens actual browser - chrome can work in headles mode so it will work with CLI. I have tried some CLI only browsers but in some cases javascript was not working well on those and ended up with actual browsers.